# On Jquery append() or prepend() how to make sure existing elements in the div aren't pushed below

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, prepend

I have a div and I'm inserting div's inside the parent div I've tried using prepend() and append() every time it pushes the existing div inside the parent div a row below or when I use append() it appends it a row below the existing div.
Is there a way to overlap the existing div and use append or prepend to insert it on top of it?

```
$scope.addNode = function(node) {

    if(!checkIfNodeExists(node)) {

        var nodeId = "node"+guid();
        var leftPlugId = "left-plug-"+guid();
        var rightPlugId = "right-plug-"+guid();

        var $div = $("<div>", {id: nodeId, "class": "node pointer", style:"top: 0px"});
        var $plugLeftDiv = $("<div>", {id: leftPlugId, "class": "node-plug-left pointer", "ng-click":"plugClicked('#"+leftPlugId+"')"});
        var $plugRightDiv = $("<div>", {id: rightPlugId, "class": "node-plug-right pointer", "ng-click":"plugClicked('#"+rightPlugId+"')"});

        $div.append($plugLeftDiv);
        $div.append($plugRightDiv);

        $("#node-container").append($compile($div)($scope));
        $div.draggable({ containment: "#main-container", scroll: false });


    }
}
```

Comment: It's about styling (using `position: absolute`, for example), not ordering your elements.

Comment: Post a code snippet to illustrate your problem. Could be a styling problem, could be an issue with how you are using jQuery but without knowing the context it's hard to say.

Comment: I can't use absolute it's a draggable div